# Why are eigenvalues so significant in DR techniques?

Tags: matrix, dimensionality-reduction

I've read PCA and few more dimension reduction algorithms and all of them talk about using eigen values and matrix operations. How are they so significant in discovering geometrical significance of data? More relevant what properties make them so relevant to Dimension Reduction

Comment: I can only add a direction. A more general theory that incorporates PCA is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem
This is heavily dependent on eigenvalues and eigenfunctions (which are themselves generalized eigenvectors). This is pretty math heavy, and over my own head, but maybe you can read it ;)

Answer (score 1):

The key reason is that the eigenvalues are invariant under similarity transforms.
Let $P$ represent the matrix of interest, e.g. a covariance matrix, with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \dots \lambda_n$.   Then the matrix $S^{-1} P S$ has the same set of eigenvalues.

We care about similarity transforms of a matrix because these correspond to linear transformations of the vector space that that matrix "operates" on.

Ultimately we want features that are characteristic of the data themselves, and do not depend on how we chose to set up the coordinate system for making our measurements.

Comment: I would like to suggest that a more fundamental reason precedes this one: the "matrix of interest" appears because we use *second order moments* of the data. Once we elect to do that, the original question amounts to asking why it is so useful to describe an ellipsoid in terms of its semi-axes--and the answer is patently obvious. Another interesting (and perhaps controversial) aspect of this reply is its implicit assumption that PCA is performed on a correlation matrix: if covariances are used instead, then the units of measurement matter and (therefore) so does the coordinate system.